# Cannot delete windows partition from mac

Tags: macos, partition, windows

I want to remove Windows from Mac and the I know the simple way is through the Boot Camp Assistant. But that doesn't work for me as follows:

[image: the remove button is greyed out]

However, when I try to merge the partition of windows through disk utility, all buttons are inactive, and I cannot press either '-' or 'option' button, like follows:

[image: cannot merge the partition]

Then, I try to reinstall a new Mac osX from the internet by pressing and holding the [command]+[alt]+[R] when starting the computer, and it doesn't work either. I am informed that the system cannot be installed in either the BOOTCAMP partition or Untitled partition since they are not GUID partition table format.

I am a newer to Mac and I just want to delete the Windows partition and add the space back to my osX partition. I wonder what should I do next?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try both repair disk (if grayed, then verify), and repair disk permissions. If you are still unable, boot to single-user mode (<kbd>Command</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd>  on boot) and type in the following.

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

Press enter, then type reboot.

If it still does not work, then do the following, but be sure to backup:

Hold <kbd>Command</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd>  on boot to start Recovery mode, select disk utility and do it from there. If it is grayed out, select the partition scheme to 1 (or 2 if you need Untitled)

---

### Warning:

There have been reports that setting the partition scheme to 1 or 2 can erase all your data. Be sure to backup before attempting to do this.

Comment: If you go so far as to select the entire device, then take this advice to set it to 1 partition and apply it, *you will lose the entire drive*.

Comment: @RayJunior I will add that, if there's a risk. It always worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so when I had a similar problem, I used Terminal, these [two](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/disk-management-from-the-command-line-part-2) [guides](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/disk-management-from-the-command-line-part-1), and this command line to get it done.

```
diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ NewName {first disk identifier in range} {last disk identifier in range}
```

I used `diskutil list` to make sure I knew which drives I was merging, because you can't use the Disk Utility names (Macintosh HD, BOOTCAMP), you need the disk identifier (which looks like disk0, disk0s1, disk0s2, etc). I'm going to ***guess*** your HD would be disk0s2 and the BC is disk0s3, if that were true the next thing you'd put into Terminal is:

```
diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ NewName disk0s2 disk0s3
```

The `JHFS+` will reformat the Windows drive when it merges and `NewName` should be replaced with whatever you wanna name your HD.

Mind you, doing the above should leave you with 2 partitions: NewName and Untitled. If you wanted to merge all three partitions then you would use HD and Untitled in your command line.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful 
diskutil mergePartitions 
is very powerful -- if you have segment A and C and merge them it gets rid of B (merges that too) -- and other very funky repercussions. So be careful.

It ultimately helped me get rid of the xfat partition but it was tricky.